# I was honored to be mentioned by such a wonderful boxer. (vs. to have been mentioned)

Tags: phrase-meaning, tense, tense-agreement

> I was honored to be mentioned by such a wonderful boxer.

> I was honored to have been mentioned by such a wonderful boxer.

Which one is more grammatical or idiomatic expression? Or both of them are grammatical or idiomatic
? Or it's just a diffrent expression in terms of 'tense'?

I know 'to + perfect tense' means 'to infinitive' precedes the main verb 'was'.

Comment: The only difference with these is the tense.  While both are grammatically correct, it's impossible to say which you should use, because you haven't provided any context.

Comment: Both are fine, and it's nit-picking to attempt to draw a semantic distinction. It's completely unnecessary to use Present Perfect for *to **have been** mentioned*,  regardless of whether the preceding context is Present *(I **am** honoured to...)* or Past *(I **was** honoured to...)* because the sequence of events is obvious anyway. The speaker couldn't feel honoured until ***after*** he was mentioned, so there's no need to use syntax to clarify the temporal relationship there. It's a stylistic choice, and my advice is the same as ever - avoid unnecessary use of Perfect forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even though your explanation is wonderful and professional, I think there is a distinct difference("marker") of event occurence in terms of 'time sequance' compared with the main verb tense.

Comment: If that's what you already think, I don't know why you asked about it here. Note that there *are* only two possible "event times" here, and their sequence is absolutely fixed (being mentioned, *followed by* feeling honoured), so there's absolutely no possibility that the form of verb can alter that. If you like using Perfect verbs, that's your choice - but unquestionably, non-native Anglophones in general overuse the Perfect form. I say if you don't *need* it, don't use it. And you don't, here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I respect your take. The reason I asked about it here is to know what exactly the difference is between the two. And now I know that there is only tense diffrence which is not significant, in fact: Both are fine—'to be mentioned' or 'to have been mentioned' are fine. Do you think there is no 'nuance difference'? Astralbee looks like he thinks there is.

Comment: I think people "construct" a difference when they see two different ways of expressing something. There's a huge difference between the **6** hits in Google Books for [*He was glad to have been asked*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22He+was+glad+to+have+been+asked%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi50YzovpP_AhVjkFwKHcKQDkYQpwV6BAgBEBU&biw=1280&bih=635&dpr=3) and **dozens** of [*He was glad to be asked.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22He+was+glad+to+be+asked%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3rpXyvpP_AhWFoVwKHRwvCJ0QpwV6BAgBEBU&biw=1280&bih=635&dpr=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's true there is a huge difference. The reason looks like 'to be' is more simple and it's obvious that he was glad after he was asked: It's no use differentiating the sequence of event, using the perfect form. Your comment was almost perfect, I think.

Comment: It's not *wrong* to use the Perfect in such contexts. But it's usually *unnecessary*, and most native speakers don't use it as often as most learners - because most speakers are "lazy" whenever they can get away with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you present when you were mentioned? Or did you find out later?

"*I was honoured to be mentioned*" sounds like the two things happened at the same time - you were mentioned, you felt honoured.

"*I was honoured to have been mentioned*" sounds like you felt honoured when you found out that you *had been* mentioned.

Comment: Yes, if you are considering careful writing, and want to draw a distinction, that is correct. But English speakers often don't use these complex past forms when the temporal relationships are clear or unimportant. Nine times out of ten, people would say the first, rather than the second, irrespective of whether they were there to hear it.

Comment: @ColinFine Your comment is of value, especially, the part of 'nine out of ten'.